# conversion from meter to pixels knowing the depth

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I have a problem with the creation of regions of interests onto an image plane.
For a set of points in the ground plane, a project fixed size windows (for instance 1x2 meters) which are scaled properly with respect to their depth.
To do this, I use a function which uses a Projection matrix from the 3D points of the space to 2d image coordinates. So basically I create the Roi by just projecting

```
 point1 << x3D-Width/2,y3D,Height,1; // with respect to the laser ref frame
 point2 << x3D+Width/2,y3D,optimalBottom,1; // with respect to the laser ref frame
```

which are the two extrema points of the rectangle and where we can assume `optimalBottom = 0.0`.

Now the problem is that if I use the Projection, which is computed from the parameters of the fisheye camera, this will lead with windows not properly positioned onto the rectified image (I need to use the rectified image). 
So I thought to do a remapping (with `opencv remap`) to remap the extrema coordinates but this lead to distortion due to the fisheye effect on the image. For instance the position of the rectangles are good but, on the lateral side of the image the width and the height of such rectngles are completely distorted. 
What turned in my mind was to remap only the original points which generate the rectangles and then adding fixed values for width and height directly expressed in pixels.

### The problem is:

> Knowing the dimensions of a rectangle and its depth, is it possible to get the conversion from meters to pixels?

For instance, I would like to have the correct values in pixels to do 
`center(projected, in pixels)-width/2(fixed, in pixels)`
`center(projected, in pixels)+width/2(fixed, in pixels)`

to find the total width of the rectangle but obviously such width must not be fixed but it must depend on the depth/distance of the rectangle.
Maybe it is a stupid problem but I cannot figure out a workaround for this. 
Thank you

Comment: Hi Jacopo, do you think you could draw your problem as a geometrical one? Here it's difficult to understand (for me at least).